# How to check group for containing certain elements in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a simple table:

```
id num

1 7
1 5
1 4

2 5
2 4
2 7

3 4
3 7
```

How to select ids having num 5 as well as 7 and 4

For this example ids: 1, 2

Comment: What is the column type of `num`? Is it a string (e.g. ID=1 Num="7 1 5 1 4")?

Comment: I think you meant ids 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table`
WHERE `num` IN (4, 5, 7)
GROUP BY `id`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: what if you get 4,4,4 in a single group?

Comment: Changing COUNT(*) = 3 to COUNT(DISTINCT `num`) = 3 should fix that

Comment: @Chris: as always such tasks are solved over unique data. i bet this question is not an exception of this "rule".

Answer (score 1):

This is a very slightly amended version of zerkms' answer:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` 
WHERE `num` IN (4, 5, 7) 
GROUP BY `id` 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `num`) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT ID, NUM, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS ROWNO,
           SUM(NUM) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS SUMNUM
    FROM TABLE
)
SELECT ID, NUM
FROM T
WHERE ROWNO = 3 AND SUMNUM = 16
```